# Getting an error : The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, formula-field, automation

I am getting an  error on the flow that is look for one with value in picklist as = Prime Contractor other being if there is no account associated with it. Should I be changing the ISBLANK to a different type type?

```
OR(
IF(ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Role__c}, "Prime Contractor"), {!$Record.Account__r.Name},{!$Record.Opportunity__r.Name})
,
IF
    (ISBLANK({!$Record.Name})
    , TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Role__c}, "Prime Contractor"), {!$Record.Account__r.Name},{!$Record.Opportunity__r.Name})
```

Returns a text value.

(ISBLANK({!$Record.Name})

Will never be true, because Name will always have a value.

```
IF
(ISBLANK({!$Record.Name})
, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

Is unnecessary, because ISBLANK already returns a true or false value.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do,  but this formula is nowhere close. You'll want to check the documentation for the correct usage.

Comment: So I am trying to get the formula to check if the value for a related record is blank. If I don't use the record.name as the correct label what would be the correct label to possibly use to check if value is not available?

Comment: @mhashif `$Record.Account__c` or `$Record.Opportunity__c`, etc.

Comment: So I tried with the $Record.Account__C and $Record.Opportunity__C and received the same error.

Comment: I figured it out, it was using data type as text when it should have been a boolean. Resolved the issue with being boolean, thanks for the help!